# Include line breaks in Dreamweaver regex for less code

Tags: regex, less, dreamweaver

I've been trying for hours to get the right regex in Dreamweaver, but I just can't get it to work. I want to take less code like below, and remove everything except the variable names-

Start:

```
font-size: @variable-for-font-size;
color: @variable-for-color;
font-style: @variable-for-font-style;
```

Desired Result

```
@variable-for-font-size
@variable-for-color
@variable-for-font-style
```

;(.*): works fine if I put the rules on the same line, but I can't get it to include the line breaks- I've tried adding \n and \r but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your regex expression here?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace by using saving groups like this:

Find:

```
^.*?:\s(.*)$
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Then, click `Replace All` button.

See also:

- [Using regular expressions – Part 2: Finding and replacing text](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html)